Implicit conversion of an std::function<void()> to void*
Considering the following code (see https://rextester.com/OAWUM62639):
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void foo( int x_ )
{
    std::cout<< "Value: " << x_ << "\n";
}

void something( void *c )
{
    auto *f = static_cast<std::function<void()>*>(c);
    (*f)();
}

int main()
{
    int x = 2;
    
    std::function<void()> lmbd = [=](){ foo(x); }; // lambda with capture.
    
    something( &lmbd ); // is this implicit conversion safe?
}

Is the implicit conversion from a std::function<void()> to a void* safe?
The code seems to be running as expected, but I am not sure about the underlying rules that the C++11 standard imposes in such situations.
A similar question is this one here: How do I pass a std::function object to a function taking a function pointer?, but the accepted answer suggests using a reinterpret_cast. Is the reinterpret_cast a necessity in this case (see https://rextester.com/ZUY69757)?

This is conversion from std::function<void()> * to a void *, and yes, it is safe. Also accepted answer in related question correctly states that it is not possible to pass ::std::function instead of pointer to function.

No the lambda in main has captures, so it is NOT convertible to a function pointer. And casting to void* in C++ is definitely not good practice and in this case not safe because the lambda isn't a (function) pointer but an object

@PepijnKramer No one mentioned conversion of lambda.

@user7860670 Fair enough. But the something function still smells. I would write function something as template<typename fn_t> something(fn_t fn) { fn(); } and forget about type conversions completely

something is a C function. I know templates would be a viable solution, but they cannot be used.

@PepijnKramer can you please elaborate on the lambda with captures? I know there is a difference when it comes to this, but not sure of the details. Can you please share the docs on this? also, the conversion is to an std::function object, not function pointer. The object's address is passed to the void* (C function). That's the part I'm not sure about.

The doc is here expr.prim.lambda in the C++ standard (not so easy to read). But it basically says : Only a lambda with no captures can be converted to a function pointer.  And yes you cast the lambda to some random pointer type and then back but it is not necessary with a template method (casts to void* should only be used in type-erasure scenarios, advanced C++ stuff, basicall where your template code can guarantee that it can be cast back to the type you put in) or when dealing with legacy "C" code.

@ConstantinosGlynos the capturing vs non-capturing issue would only apply if you were passing the lambda itself to something() as a C-style function pointer. But you are not doing that, so the issue is moot. You are wrapping the lambda inside of a std::function object, and then passing an object pointer to something().  ANY object pointer can safely be converted to a void* and then back to the original object.

@Constantinos Glynos "something is a C function. " -- how is "something" a C function if it converts void* to std::function*? Dou you mean C++ function with C-linkage?

@Gene: You are correct to be confused with this, but please note that I have simplified the code to the bare minimum for this post. The original code would have made this question unnecessarily complex. Just assume that the something function's signature is defined in C.


Is the implicit conversion from a std::function<void()> to a void* safe?

All of the shown code is safe.
In general, for any object of type T it is completely fine to convert a pointer to it to void* and then static_cast it back to T* to then use it.
The tricky bits about such an interface are:

Casting to void* loses type information, but you must cast back to the exact original type to use the pointed-to object. Casting to any other type will likely end in undefined behavior. So, usually the only reasonable behavior for such an interface is to only copy the pointer value itself and pass the pointer back to context provided by the user, which knows the actual type.

You lose any ownership semantics. The void* pointer is always purely observing. It doesn't carry any ownership. Therefore the caller has to make sure that the actual object (i.e. lmbd) outlives any use of the void* pointer by something. If something stores the pointer somewhere for e.g. a later callback, that can become tricky.


These kind of interfaces are sometimes necessary when interacting with C, but for pure C++ code there is no need to do it this way. Templates or passing std::function directly are superior solutions.

Thank you for this clear explanation. :-)
